# PhongGap Android Phone Call comes in event

Tags: android, cordova, phone-call

I am making an android app using PhoneGap version 1.4.1

I have some flash content(Video with sound) in my application. My problem is, the video keeps playing even when the phone call comes in. So when user answers the phone call he hears the sound from video.
Is there an event that triggers when phone call comes in?

Following is my code,

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("**phonecall**", **onPhoneCall**, false);
}

function **onPhoneCall**(){
    pauseVideo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no phonecall event

You can try to use the pause event, it should be called on phone call

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
    // pause the video here
}
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause